# Decrease Date for Average on this SQL

Tags: sql, average

I want to query price average from my top 25 price sort by last date (and select some symbols).

I use this code, It's Work !!

```
SELECT AVG(PRICE)
    FROM (SELECT PRICE FROM ms_data where SYMBOL='$symbol' 
ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 25) var;
```

If I don't want top date or 2 top date.

Example.

top date (lastest date) = 2014-04-16

2nd of top date = 2014-04-15

3rd of top date = 2014-04-4

...

I should not query first result,right?

I use this code but It doesn't work.

```
SELECT AVG(PRICE)
    FROM (SELECT PRICE FROM ms_data where SYMBOL='$symbol' AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT PRICE FROM ms_data where SYMBOL='$symbol'
ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 26) var;
```

If use variable instead of limit.

```
SELECT AVG(PRICE)
    FROM (SELECT PRICE FROM ms_data where SYMBOL='$symbol' AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT PRICE FROM ms_data where SYMBOL='$symbol'
ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT $i) ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 25+$i) var;
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not getting question. If date =2014-04-16 having 5 transactions you want to take all and you don't want to consider 5 records instead of you want count 1 right?

Comment: 1 date only have 1 transaction (for 1 symbol).
if I don't want top date or 2nd or 3rd date. what i should to do?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I use mysql and i tried to query that syntax on phpmyadmin.

Comment: [Solved] I just use parameter of limit,
if i don't want top date (1st transaction) use:

`SELECT CLOSE
FROM ms_data_1
WHERE SYMBOL =  'BBL'
ORDER BY DATE DESC 
LIMIT 1 , 25`